# Proving additional formula for probability

Tags: probability

using the axioms of probability prove that $P(E \cup F) = P(E) +P(F) - P(E \cap F)$

I tried using that $E\cup F + (E \backslash F) \cup (E\cap F) \cup (F \backslash E)$

then $P(E \cup F) = P(E \backslash F) + P(E \cap F) + P(F \backslash E)$ using the fact that if $A,B$ are disjoint then $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ however I am not sure what to do here!

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Addition_Law_of_Probability) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're on a good track:
$$P(E\cup F) = P(E\setminus F) + P(E\cap F) + P(F\setminus E) + P(E\cap F) - P(E\cap F)$$
will be the next. Now use
$$P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^C) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\setminus B)$$
to arrive at qed.